# What is the reciprocal term for "sandak"?

Tags: minhag, hebrew, brit-milah

What is the reciprocal term for "sandak", if there is one? That is, if I am a baby's sandak, he is my _____?

Comment: The exact term would be something in Greek since sandak is most probably from the Greek *syndikus*. In rabbinic jargon it's simply נער or ילד הנימול. In English it'd probably be 'godchild'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The rabbinic terms you mentioned are more generally about the child, or the child in relation to the brit ceremony. I'm asking about the term for the on-going relationship -- basically, if there is a Hebrew or Yiddish or other Jewish term for "godchild" as you say.

Comment: @CanisNebula I understand; interesting q. AFAIK there is no such term in rabbinic jargon or Yiddish. Interestingly though, in Yiddish there is an oft-used term "קוואטער אינגעל" but that's reserved for the reciprocal of 'קוואטער', not סנדק.

Comment: @Oliver That is interesting to note. 

I'm finding that anywhere I see sandak translated to anything, it's godfather, so I guess godson is the best I'll find.